# Setting a limit within touchesbegan method

Tags: ios, character, touchesbegan

So I am using the touchesBegan method in my program in `Xcode`. When the user touches the screen, the character goes up the `y axis`, and when touches ended the user goes down. The problem I'm having is that the character is able to go off the screen (below 0 or above 768 `[ipad]` on the `y axis`).

How can I make it so that if the user touches the screen, and the character gets to `y axis 0`, the character will just stay there even if the user continues to touch. As well, if the user ends touch, how can I make sure the character doesn't go past 768.

I entered in a bunch of different if conditionals but the closest I got was to get the character to stay at 0 or 768, but when the user `ended touch` or `began touch` again, the character would just stay at 0 or 768. Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `touchesBegan:`

```
//[animation begins]
character.frame = CGRectMake(character.frame.origin.x, 0, character.frame.size.width, character.frame.size.height);
//[animation ends]
```

In `touchesEnded:`

```
//[animation begins]
character.frame = CGRectMake(character.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.size.height - character.frame.size.height), character.frame.size.width, character.frame.size.height);
//[animation ends]
```